# Java data structure to have a method trigger something only after being called N times

Tags: java, data-structures, rate

What data structure might be nice to use for triggering something only after a method has been called N times? It's trivial to use a counter within a class, but I'm wondering if there's a nicer way to do this. This is kind of like a reverse rate-limiter in some sense.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
  call();
}

void call() {
   // trigger only once per 100 calls.
   // e.g. static int i = 0; if (++i % 100) doSomething();
}
```

Comment: I think a thread-safe `private static` counter is fine.

Comment: What's wrong with a basic counter?

Comment: Trivial is perfectly acceptable and usually preferable. Why do you want to add complexity?  Is there a problem you're trying to solve other than "it's not nice enough"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), like this:

```
private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
```

Then in your `call()` method do this:

```
if (counter.incrementAndGet() == N) {
    do {
        actualCall();
    } while (counter.addAndGet(-N) >= N);
}
```

Note that `actualCall()` may not be called from the exact invocation that incremented the number to reach `N`. For example, if other threads would bring the counter to `2*N` while `actualCall` is in progress, `addAndGet(-N)` would return a value of `N`, so the loop would continue, and invoke `actualCall` again. However, there would be one call of `actualCall` per `N` calls of `call()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably elaborate the context and intentions. If this is intended for reducing some debug output that is spilled to the console with `System.out.println`, then a simple counter will be fine.

Otherwise, there are several options with a varying degree of "invasiveness" and "abstraction".

The first questions will then be whether this counting should be based on the instance or whether it should be based on the class (static), and maybe whether it should the thread-safe or not.

For the simplest case, you can use what you already proposed in the question, and what dasblinkenlight confirmed (for the static, thread-safe case).

A slightly higher level of abstraction could be an interface like this:

```
interface CallPropagator {
    boolean shouldPropagateCall();
}

class CountingCallPropagator implements CallPropagator {
    private final int maxCount;
    private int count = 0;
    CountingCallPropagator(int maxCount) {
        this.maxCount = maxCount;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldPropagateCall() {
        count++;
        if (count >= maxCount) {
            count = 0;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then guard your method with one of these:

```
class YourClass {
    private CallPropagator c = new CountingCallPropagator(100);

    void call() {
        if (c.shouldPropagateCall()) {
            // Really do it...
        }
    }
}
```

The nice thing is that you could create an alternative implementation like `TimedCallPropagator` that only forwards the call not based on the call *count*, but based on the time - e.g. only very 10 seconds or so.

But still, the decision about whether the actual work has to be performed is rather explicit, **in** your implementation class that then **does** the actual work.

The next higher level of abstraction would be to remove the use of `YourClass#call()` at the call site altogether, and completely replace it with an interface. So you would "hide" the *decision* of whether a call is forwarded or not from the call site itself **and** from the object that is called, offering the option to "wrap" the original callee into one that only executes its work at a fixed interval.

That is, given that your current structure looks like this:

```
class Caller {
    void doCalls() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            call();
        }
    }
}
```

you could introduce an interface like `Callee`

```
class Caller {

    private Callee callee = ...;

    void doCalls() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            callee.call();
        }
    }
}
```

and then offer various implementations of this interface. For example

```
class DirectCallee implements Callee {
    @Override 
    public void call() {
        // Do the actual work here
    }
}


class IntervalCallee implements Callee {

    private final Callee delegate;
    private final int maxCount;
    private int count = 0;

    IntervalCallee(int maxCount, Callee delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.maxCount = maxCount;
    }

    @Override 
    public void call() {
       count++;
       if (count >= maxCount) {
           count=0;
           delegate.call();
       }
    }
}
```

or again, one that performs a time-based forwarding (or even offer combinations, like "Forward every 10th call, if the last 3 calls happened within 3 seconds" or so...)